# PHP Code Igniter cannot show data in modal bootstrap

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, bootstrap-modal

I'm using codeigniter franmework. I try to appear the data into a modal. but i have a problem with my datas. They don't appear in modal. I followed the tutorial on the internet but it doesn't work. Here is my button click code which purposed to show data :

```
<a href="javascript:;"
data-id="<?php echo $row->id ?>"
data-kode="<?php echo $row->kode ?>"
data-subkode="<?php echo $row->subkode ?>"
data-nama_kegiatan="<?php echo $row->nama_kegiatan ?>"
data-toggle="modal" data-target="#edit-data">
<button  data-target="#ubah-data" data-toggle="modal" class="btn btn-info">Ubah</button>
</a>
```

This is my modal code

```
<div aria-hidden="true" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" role="dialog" tabindex="-1" id="edit-data" class="modal fade">
<div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button aria-hidden="true" data-dismiss="modal" class="close" type="button">×</button>
            <h4 class="modal-title">Ubah Data</h4>
        </div>
        <form class="form-horizontal" action="<?php echo base_url('dashboard/rka2/ubah')?>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" role="form">
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-lg-2 col-sm-2 control-label">Kode</label>
                    <div class="col-lg-10">
                        <input type="hidden" id="id" name="id">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="kode" name="kode">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-lg-2 col-sm-2 control-label">Subkode</label>
                    <div class="col-lg-10">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="subkode" name="subkode">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-lg-2 col-sm-2 control-label">Nama Kegiatan</label>
                    <div class="col-lg-10">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="nama_kegiatan" name="nama_kegiatan">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button class="btn btn-info" type="submit"> Simpan&nbsp;</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning" data-dismiss="modal"> Batal</button>
            </div>
        </form>
     </div>
</div>
```

And this is the script for getting datas

```
    <script>
$(document).ready(function() {

    // Untuk sunting
    $('#edit-data').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {
        var div = $(event.relatedTarget) // Tombol dimana modal di tampilkan
        var modal          = $(this)

        // Isi nilai pada field
        modal.find('#id').attr("value",div.data('id'));
        modal.find('#kode').attr("value",div.data('kode'));
        modal.find('#subkode').attr("value",div.data('subkode'));
        modal.find('#nama_kegiatan').attr("value",div.data('nama_kegiatan'));
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please edit your code so it'll be minimal, precise and will match your question clearly

Comment: does the console should any javascript error?

Comment: Please go through [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: no but the data cannot appear in my modal @KimberleeHo

Comment: @FatimahBadriyah just check if you are getting data in  `$row` as I tried your code and it is working

Comment: @Piyush yeah sir, it's worked, i already get the datas but doesn't appear in the modal when i call it